# Using "->" instead of "." to access structure gives Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers

I made a typedef structure in somefile.h and declared in somefile.c as

```
somestruct *mystruct;
```

and accessed as

```
somevar = mystruct->variable;
```

then it produces "Segmentation Fault"(probably StackOverflow since there is a "while" loop).
But if I use it as

```
somestruct mystruct;
somevar = mystruct.variable;
```

then no problem.

whats wrong??

Comment: Did you ever allocate *any* memory for `*mystruct`? A pointer is just a pointer, there's not automatically any object attached...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`somestruct *mystruct` defines a pointer to memory of type `somestruct` and does not point to anything, or better if it is local variable then it is not initialized and this is *Undefined Behaviour*.

If you do this `somestruct mystruct` then you define struct itself and not a pointer (object exists in memory).

To use pointer access, you should reserve memory for your struct like:

```
somestruct *mystruct = malloc(sizeof(*mystruct));
mystruct->variable = 5;
```

Or you can also do this:

```
somestruct mystruct; //Create my structure in memory
somestruct *mystruct_ptr = &mystruct; //Create pointer to that structure and assign address
mystruct_ptr->variable = 10; //Write to mystruct using pointer access
```

Answer (score 0):

If the following produces a segfault:

```
somestruct *mystruct;
somevar = mystruct->variable;
```

It's probably all the code there is. The first line just defines a **pointer** to a `somestruct`. The pointer isn't initialized, it points to some undefined location. There's nowhere an actual object of type `somestruct`.

Dereferencing this pointer is **undefined behavior** -- your program will try to read from / write to some unknown location, the OS *might* catch this and kill your program with a *segmentation fault*.

To actually use a pointer, it must point to some object. If you have some `somestruct` somewhere, you can make your pointer point to that:

```
somestruct foo;
somestruct *mystruct = &foo;
somevar = mystruct->variable;
```

If you want to *create* a new `somestruct`, you can do a dynamic allocation (include `stdlib.h`):

```
somestruct *mystruct = malloc(sizeof(*mystruct));
// use *mystruct
// when done, don't forget:
free(mystruct);
```